# Sign up event from Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

How would I know that a person on my website has just completed the 'Sign Up' process in Azure B2C? Would I have to store my own list of object ids and check against it? I get the feeling I am going to have to do that in any case...

Answer (score 6):

You receive the 'newUser' boolean claim if you have this selected in the signup policy. This will only be sent once, so you need to act on this.

Comment: At what point should I act on this? Every time a user logs into my app, do I check for the presence of the newUser claim and run my custom "sign up" logic then?

Comment: Yes, that's the case

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to store a list of object id's & verify accordingly in your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this...

**Step 1 (Azure Portal)**

- In Azure Portal navigate to ADB2C, click on your Sign up and sign in policy
- Click on Application claims and make sure to Tick the "User is new" claim

The "User is new" claim will be sent only if the user has just signed-up
[image]

**Step 2 (Code)**

//Using OpenIdConnectOptions

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
{
            OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
            OnRemoteFailure = OnRemoteFailure,
            OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
            OnAuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
            OnMessageReceived = OnMessageReceived,
            OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut,
            OnRemoteSignOut = OnRemoteSignOut,
            OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect,
            OnTicketReceived = _onTicketReceivedInternal,
            OnTokenResponseReceived = OnTokenResponseReceived,
            OnTokenValidated = OnTokenValidated,
            OnUserInformationReceived = OnUserInformationReceived
};
```

Notice the _onTicketReceivedInternal Task...

```
private Task _onTicketReceivedInternal(TicketReceivedContext context)
{
        this.OnTicketReceived(context);

        //Check if new user
        Claim newUserClaim = context.Principal.Claims.ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "newUser");
        bool newUser = newUserClaim == null ? false : true;

        //Trigger event
        if (newUser)
            this.OnSignUp(context);


        return Task.FromResult(0);
}

//Custom method OnSignUp where an application can do something on user sign up
protected virtual Task OnSignUp(TicketReceivedContext context)
{
        return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```