# How to get logger/configuration into a static class for OnTicketReceived event of AAD B2C using Razor Pages and dotnetcore 3.1

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, azure-ad-b2c, razor-pages

I am using Azure B2C in a Razor Pages web app on dotnet core 3.1 and I want to log information to my database whenever a user is added or changed. I also want to confirm a user is in the database when they sign in, and add them if they are not. Right now I'm just trying to get the "new user" running. I don't know how to get logging and configuration into my static class given the event has a specific signature.

```
    public UserRepository(ILogger<UserRepository> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
```

I have been following [this article](https://wellsb.com/csharp/aspnet/azure-ad-b2c-onticketreceived-newuser-claim/?unapproved=1870&moderation-hash=b9372b3f63a862fcc006698281af9683#comment-1870) and I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097669/sign-up-event-from-azure-b2c/56250604#56250604) and have implemented a static class with:

```
    public async static Task<Task> OnTicketReceivedCallback(TicketReceivedContext context)
    {
        //OnTicketReceived
        //Check if user just completed signup flow
        List<Claim> claims = context.Principal.Claims.ToList();
        bool isNewUser = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "newUser") == null ? false : true;

        //If so, do what needs to be done
        if (isNewUser)
        {
            //This is where I am getting the error and don't know how to push the logger and configuration through the stack
            UserRepository repo = new UserRepository();

        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Being called from the startup:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");


        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            options.Events.OnTicketReceived = B2CExtensions.OnTicketReceivedCallback
        );

        services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make OnTicketReceivedCallback class non static and register it as a singleton. That way you can pass an ILogger trough the constructor.